# updating total items in pagination

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-pagination in my Angular 4 app and an example of what I'm trying to do can be found here: http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging

However, there is one small difference in the functionality that I want. The example shows a server call in which the total number of items in the response is returned:

```
function serverCall(meals: string[], page: number): Observable<IServerResponse> {
const perPage = 10;
const start = (page - 1) * perPage;
const end = start + perPage;

return Observable
    .of({
        items: meals.slice(start, end),
        total: 100
    }).delay(1000);
```

}

This `total` is then used to determine how many pages to show in the pagination component. However, the server call I am making only returns an estimate of the number of items that the result could have (as I am querying the server page-by-page). The "estimate" gets more and more accurate with each change in page, so ideally I would like to be able to update the `totalItems` property asynchronously so that the number of pages is adjusted accordingly.

I have tried something like this:

```
<ul class="meal-list">
    <li *ngFor="let meal of asyncMeals | async | paginate: this.config">
        {{ meal }}
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="has-text-centered">
    <div class="spinner" [ngClass]="{ 'hidden': !loading }"></div>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPage($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

where `this.config` points to a config object in the typescript class. I am updating the totalItems value in this config as soon as a more accurate estimate is being generated, however, the pagination component keeps using the original estimate. I tried to add an `async` flag to the config object, but this results in an error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config passed into the paginate pipe should not have `this`. your properties in your html only come from your component's class so `config` in your html is equivalent to `this.config` in your typescript. Try changing to

```
<li *ngFor="let meal of asyncMeals | async | paginate: config">
    {{ meal }}
</li>
```

I was able to create a plnkr of what I think you are going for. (http://plnkr.co/edit/GjeAP0XpbSoRU2bI7GxE?p=preview)

Comment: I did manage to figure it out eventually prior to you posting this answer, doing something very similar to what you have done. Just had to separate the config file from the template and update the value of total items as soon as the server response produced a better estimate. Thank you!